# Laravel Model Relationships

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, laravel, eloquent

I am playing around with Laravel Models and i came across a fairly common database design pattern for which i am unable to establish relationships (using Laravel).

Here is the [`Database design`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9phduxulrojk2xn/Screenshot%202013-11-03%2005.09.20.png)

If we only take into consideration the following tables (for simplicity):
1.Customers
2.Products
3.Product_Prices (The products price is expected to change over time and we need to keep track)
4.Customer_Orders
5.Customer_Orders_Products (A customer can order multiple products in a single order)

Here is what i have so far:
1. Product `HAS MANY` Product_Prices
2. Product_Prices `BELONGS TO` Products
3. Customer `HAS MANY` Customer_Orders
4. Customer_Order `BELONGS TO` Customer
5. Customer_Order `HAS MANY` Customer_Order_Products
6. Customer_Order_Products `BELONGS TO` Customer_Order

I think that the `Price` for each `Customer_Order_Products` will be fetched by establishing a relationship to the `Products` table? How do we establish such a relationship?

How to get an `Laravel Collection Object` with the following details (I am not sure if only `Eloquent` returns a collection object or if its the same with `Fluent`):
1. `Customer` WITH `Customer_Orders` WITH `Customer_Orders_Products` WITH `Product_Price` ?

Also how to put constrains like:
1. `Customer` WITH `Customer_Orders` WITH `Customer_Orders_Products` WITH `Product_Price` WHERE `Product_Price < Customers_Order.date_order_placed` ?

Thanks

Comment: After some searching and some testing on my own, I don't believe this is possible using Eloquent relationships.  Your best bet would probably be using the query builder and manually join all these tables.  The `Product_Price < Customers_Order.date_order_placed` is the culprit.

Comment: @user1669496 Yes, that is exactly where i am stuck.. I'll try the query builder though i am not sure if it returns a Laravel collection object. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think de-normalizing the database to include the price in Customer_Order_Products and then use following relationship would be better idea.

```
class CustomerOrder {
    protected $table = 'Customer_Orders';

    ...

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Products')->withPivot('quantity','comments', 'price');
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: How do i manage multiple prices for the same product and keep record of dates when the price change was made?

Comment: Still you have to keep `product_prices` table to keep the record of historical prices. As far as I understand, item in `Customer_Orders_Products` has one fixed price and it has no relation to the varying price. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Yes that is correct but then it means duplicate data.. i am trying to find a better way, thanks

Comment: Yes, denormalizing introduces duplicate data, but sometimes it is necessary to ensure acceptable performance level in database. This article is a good read about denormalization. 

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505841.aspx

Comment: Actually performance is not the issue for me as i will be caching the results from DB. The product prices and ordered products are not something that will change often.. maybe once in 2 months or so.. even longer.. so i prefer keeping my DB as compact as possible..

Comment: I got rid of the `product_prices` table and maintain the prices in two table `products` (current price) and `Customer_Orders_Products` (price when ordered) and also have a new `revisions` table where i store price history as well as history related to other Models. This way i do not have to query multiple tables and i have removed dependency. I like the flexibility :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case the Customer_Orders_Products isn't just a fancy join table, but a model of it's own with a relationship to the Product_Prices table.

Add a product_price_id to the table to map the ordered product to the price.

This adds flexibility (maybe the price is determined by volume later instead of 'recentness') at almost the same overhead cost as storing the price directly.